# Multiple Connection Poolers not returning connections to pool in Spring

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using dbcp2  (2.1.1  with MySql) and my connections are hanging in a sleep state.  I have triple chekced my code and I am closing all my connections in the finally block....  However,  after 10 calls to the DB... the system hangs.

I am however using multiple connection pools.  like this:

```
<bean id="onedataSource"    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    ...
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxTotal" value="10" />
</bean>

<bean id="twodataSource"    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <...
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxTotal" value="10" />
</bean>

<bean id="threedataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
   ...
   <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
   <property name="maxTotal" value="10" />
</bean>
```

The reason for this is we have 3 different schemas with different names/passwords

Am I doing this wrong?  How do I return connections back to the pool?

EDIT:  using the logger,  I can say that the datasource.getConnection()  is where the code is hanging.

When I run SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST  I get these:  The "state" is blank, the "command" is Sleep

```
'2205592', 'user', '10.0.0.87:48520', 'oneschema', 'Sleep', '8975', '', NULL
```

***UPDATE***

So I thought it might be the connection pooler itself.  So I go and change one of them to HikariCP  (which by itself, dropped some calls from 6 seconds to 1.5  so I highly recommend it over dbcp, but I digress)   I restart,  and preso!  everything is working great.  No hanging, connections being returned to the pool.  All is right with the world.

Naturally,  I then go and change the other 2,  and presto!  The errors are back!  There is definitely something wrong with how Spring is handling multiples of the same class and datasources.

Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Without looking at the code, it will be difficult to pin point exact problem. IMO you should check which statement is causing system to hang. Usually `getConnection()` would end up waiting for a new connection from the pool if no connection is free.

Comment: Yes,  the conn.getConnection()  is hanging.  I can see in the MySql workbench,  that I am maxed out in connections,  and all of them are in sleep mode.

Comment: Run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to see which connection is stuck doing what. I don't think connections in sleep mode can cause this issue.

Comment: Edited question with SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST results

Comment: Only one connection ? You need to run this as a root user

Comment: Oh no,  there were 10 of these,  all the same thing.  (Different ID of course) 10 being the max connections in the pool